# How Can I Make Haunted House Ambient Music?

Tags: music, foley, animation, horror, dark

I'm currently working on a cartoon that involves a cartoon character going cuckoo for a cereal box toy in an asylum and I got some things that I want to keep in mind for the music and sound design. It's based on this fan art piece. https://www.deviantart.com/realmofquickpaw/art/Bunny-Huggles-59456126

For the music I wanna reference Rory O'Neill's piece for Club Penguin's Halloween Party of 2011. It's called Haunted Mansion

. I know that there's an organ and Theremin in it, but what else is there besides the mentioned instruments?

Comment: I have edited the post down to 1 question as per guidance on [ask] - feel free to ask the Foley question as a separate one.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new here, so sorry if I get confused here.

Comment: No worries - the community will keep you right. You got an upvote from me for this one anyway

Comment: That's good. I love getting upvotes.

Comment: Long drone pads with lots of reverb.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the wind with a noise that you filter with a high pass filter and then with a low pass filter with resonance while you change the low pass frequency constantly.

You can create the theremin effect by using an sinus ocillator and adding an lfo on its pitch. Using a formant filter makes it sound even creepier on it.

Here is a demonstration: